# Is using declared and initialized but undefined variables undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, static, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

In C++ you can have a class `C` declared in `c.h` which contains the declaration and initialization of `static const int var = 3;`.

```cpp
class C {
public:
...
    static const int var = 3
...
};
```

Unless you make that variable [inline](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r0.pdf), or explicitly define it in your `c.cpp`,

```cpp
...
const int C::var;
...
```

it is undefined.

- So, is even using `var` in not memory address-related things, like a
  counter in a for loop undefined behavior?
- How does the compiler use the value of an undefined variable? Does
  the preprocessor macro-substitute its value?
- In addition to this case of a static int variable in a class
  declaration, is there any other circumstance where you can have
  declared and initialized but undefined variables?
- Can this happen in the C programming language?

I know there must be some sort of mechanism to make this work as I've seen C++ code which uses undefined static const variables. But I would appreciate citing the standard.

Comment: Are you aware of `extern int var;` in c.h? It's the same - using var is not UB . It's initialized in some of c.c. You must know that global initializations happen before main() call.

Comment: Giving a code example (fragment) would lend more credence to your post.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews done. Thanks for the edit and suggestions.

Comment: There is no UB. Because this is ill-formed (Your code should not compile). You cannot have an initializer for non-`const` `static` class members inside a class definition. For the other question, the answer is no. You can't have anything like that in standard C, either.

Comment: If this is C++, and you just use the value, even the most stupid compiler can see that `var` means `3` and just use that value when the code says `var`. If you were to take its address, or pass it by reference, a definition would be needed. Historically this meant in some .cpp file.

Comment: @BoP But is this "compiler can see that var means 3" standard? Could there be a compiler compliant with C++ standard that failed to recognize that because of it being undefined?

Comment: @ChristmasTree - But it literally says `var = 3` in the code. If your compiler doesn't understand that, you want to use a different compiler. :-) And nowadays you would use `constexpr` and/or `inline` anyway. The discussions about needing a separate definition is just old.

Comment: *But I would appreciate citing the standard.*  You should add the `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: @BoP I know it's probably not relevant in a practical sense, I'm just curious to understand the language.

Comment: @ChristmasTree - Not to put your enthusiasm down, but trying to learn exactly everything about C++ is just an enourmous task. It is much better to focus on the parts that you have an immediate use for. Here is Bjarne on [why he doesn't want to know everything about C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VI21tpdkHA8&t=3469s).

Comment: @BoP That's actually very inspiring. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [[class.static.data]/4 sentence 1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.static#data-4.sentence-1) this construct for static data members is allowed as an exception from the general rule only if `var` has a `const`-qualified integral or enumeration type and is initialized by a [*constant expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#11).

Per [[basic.def.odr]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr#10) (reaffirmed by [[class.static.data]/4 sentence 2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.static#data-4.sentence-2)) a definition of `var` is required iff `var` is [*odr-used*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr#4.2). Otherwise the program is IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required).

Generally a variable is always odr-used if it is named in a [*potentially-evaluated expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr#2.sentence-1) outside a [*discarded statement*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/stmt.if#2.sentence-2).

However, because `var` is of `const` integral or enumeration type and initialized with a constant expression, it is *usable in constant expressions* (and can't have mutable subobjects) and therefore the exception in [[basic.def.odr]/4.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr#4.2) may apply even if `var` is named in a potentially-evaluated expression. This exception essentially applies if all you do with `var` in the expression is to immediately read its value ([*lvalue-to-rvalue conversion*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.lval)), instead of e.g. forming a pointer/reference to it. Because the variable is initialized with a constant expression the compiler can just replace the use of the variable with the compile-time constant value given to `var`.

As @LanguageLawyer points out in the comments under this answer, the standard currently says in [[intro.object]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#intro.object-1.sentence-2) that *definitions* can create objects, but not that *declarations* in general can. This is a problem, because then even if you do not violate ODR per the above exception without a definition for `var`, you still wouldn't have an object, but the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is specified in terms of reading the *object*'s value (or depending on interpretation not at all when the ODR exception applies). Absent a defined behavior the program would still have undefined behavior when evaluating the expression. However, this is clearly unintended and a defect in the standard.

There is another minor exception in [[basic.def.odr]/4.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr#4.3) for when the variable is named essentially immediately as a [*discarded-value expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr#context-2), e.g. when writing `var;` as a statement. In that case neither value nor address of `var` is needed by the compiler.

None of this has anything to do with the preprocessor, which works exclusively before even parsing of the actual C++ code.

This is I think the only exception where you can have an initializing declaration of a variable that is not at the same time a definition of the variable. It exists only for historical reasons from before `constexpr` and `inline` could be used on variables to make values of static data members usable in constant expressions.

Comment: There is a problem with such declarations-not-definitons — «an object is created by a definition»

Comment: Hallelujah! This is great stuff. Thank you, I respect the time and effort that went in.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Added a paragraph on the problem I think you are referring to.

Comment: The problem is also a bit more fundamental — lvalues denote objects . A couple of years ago I asked in Core if this is a new candidate for an «empty» lvalue, but for some reason folks were not fans of this idea

Comment: The "historical reasons" is a good point.  In modern C++, there are clearer ways to express the intent.  (Alas, the language will likely support the vestigial anomaly in perpetuity for the sake of backwards compatibility.  Unless something like Sutter's "C++ syntax 2" gains some traction.)

Answer (score 3):

> *Can this happen in the C programming language?*

In C, if you define a variable `static int var = 3;` in a header file, each C source file that includes this header file will have its own local copy if `var` defined.  There is no such thing as *declared and initialized but undefined variables*.

Note that the compiler, if configured to produce useful warnings will report unused `static` variables so you should get multiple warnings unless you use `var` is every source file.

Global `const` definition have subtly different semantics in C and C++, but this is a different question.

Comment: This is not true: "If you define a variable static int var = 3; in a header file". You don't define it, unless it's inline it violates [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

Comment: This answer only addresses the C part of the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that @chqrlie. Thanks for your time.